# How to parse JSONs in Hive with Mixed Struct/String values for a single field?

Tags: sql, json, hive, hiveql, hive-serde

I've got JSON data whose structure is similar to this:

```
root
 |-- TX: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ARGS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- COOKIE: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

The way the data is *actually* formatted, the `ARGS` array contains structs (a name-value pair just like the `COOKIE` array), like this:

```
ARGS: {"name": "url", "value": "/index.html"}
```

However, in some rows of the file, the `ARGS` array contains only a null value, which forces Hive's interpretation of it as a string:

```
ARGS: null
```

Since I know that all of the non-null values in `ARGS` are structs, I'm using a `CREATE` statement in Hive like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ${db}.${table}(
    tx struct<
        args:array<struct<name:string,value:string>>,
        cookie:array<struct<name:string,value:string>>
    >
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '${uri}';
```

Since the ultimate goal here is to lateralize the array of key value pairs, I'm using a query like this to test things out:

```
SELECT array_pairs.name, array_pairs.value 
FROM ${db}.${table}
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(tx.args) EXPLODED_TABLE AS array_pairs;
```

This works fine if I just view the first 100 or so rows in Hue. But if I try and export it as a CSV or use a `WHERE` clause that reads the entire table, Hive pops this error due to the data type mismatch:

```
errorMessage='java.lang.Error: Data is not JSONObject but java.lang.String with value alpha'
```

I know that the *best* answer is to have a perfect data source, but in this case, the data is what it is, and I've got to parse it. Any tips on how to deal with null values in a JSON with Hive parsing?

**EDIT 10/24/2019 07:43**

Thanks to @leftjoin I realized that apart from the null values, there are one or two JSON objects where the `ARGS` field is populated by a single string within the array:

```
ARGS: ["string value"]
```

Given this, is there any way that these strings can be ignored by the Hive parser, so that the key-value pairs can be extracted?

Comment: This is not because of nulls. Check for literals instead of structs

Comment: Darn, you're right. I've added an edit with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [SerDe property](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) to ignore malformed JSON:

```
ALTER TABLE json_table SET SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that yields the same query error once the table structure is changed.